# How would people set up a prison for an air bender?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Throughout both series, we were presented with several ways of imprisoning water benders, fire bender and earth benders, from gigantic complexes such as the [Boiling Rock](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Boiling_Rock) to portable cells (i.e. the metal cells they carried Toph once, before she could metalbend).

But my question is, how do you set up a prison, in a large scale, or in a permanent state, for an air bender or a group of air benders?

I know air benders are presented to us as the most peaceful ones, being monks, etc., but I find it hard to believe that inside their society they didn't have criminals or people that needed to be imprisoned. So how would they go about it?

PS: I tried looking for a question like this and didn't find it. Please let me know if this is a duplicate.

Comment: the metal cage they used on Toph would probably hold an air bender as well

Comment: @childcat15 wouldn't them easily break free by just airbending and breaking the cage?

Comment: Can you break metal with air? I don't think we've seen that in either show

Comment: Can't a hurricane rip off metal from its hinges? If you have enough pressure, it's possible. A powerful enough air bender could handle it, I guess. @childcat15

Comment: perhaps, now I'm tempted to try to research what velocity winds a hurricane would have to have to break a steel chain. But if you make the cage small enough that the prisoner has no maneuverability (restrict their arms in particular), I doubt even the best airbender could break open a steel cage with just his/her breath

Comment: Have a device that will force feed him meat if he tries to airbend

Answer (score 11):

A prison for an Airbender is covered in The Legend of Korra - Book 4: Episode 9 - Beyond the Wilds

Zaheer a member of the Red Lotus who becomes an airbender has been imprisoned after his defeat in the final episode of Book 3.

The prison for him was built from an old airbender temple inside of a mountain so the only way to it was by air or along a river. Inside an elevator was needed to go deep underground where a single room was created with one entrance, two metalbenders operate the two thick metal doors granting access to the room. Inside he was chained to the floor with chains attached to his hands, waist and feet.

[image]

Comment: the op asks for a large scale prison

Comment: Well its s prison for one insanely overpowered airbender, so deep under a mountain would be best. And op asked for an air bender or a group of air benders

Comment: Yes, and did this prison was set up before or after he became an airbender?

Comment: The prison was setup afterwards.